# nested json custom converter in c# with JavascriptConverter

Tags: c#, json

I have a json custom converter using the standard asp.net library.
My converter looks like this:

```
public class MyObjectToJson : JavaScriptConverter

  public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
  {
     MyObject TheObject = obj as MyObject;
     Dictionary<string, object> OutputJson = new Dictionary<string, object>();

     OutputJson.Add("SomeProperty", TheObject.Property1);

     //line that I'm not figuring out
     //I have a type MyNestedObject nested in the object model of MyObject
     //I added that nested converter in the SupportedTypes method    

     OutputJson.Add("TheNestedObject",....?);

     return OutputJson;
   }

   public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
   {
      get { return new Type[] { typeof(MyObject), typeof(MyNestedObject) }; }
   }
```

Basically, I have another json custom converter that's called MyNestedObjectJson but I'm wondering where to plug it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I figured it out. I'm adding this answer for those who land on this page through google. It's really so super simple:

In the calling code, you register the converter of the nested object like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer TheSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

TheSerializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { 
  new MyObjectToJson(), new MyNestedObjectToJson() 
});
```

And then, in the json converter of the parent object, you simply write the line I had trouble with like this:

```
OutputJson.Add("TheNestedObject", TheObject.TheNestedObject);
```

Since the serializer has both converters registered, the converter of the nested object will kick in.

Hope this helps some.

Comment: Small addition: Each converted returns it's own type in `SupportedTypes`. Not both as shown in initial post